# Video and Audio are out of sync in iMovie export

Tags: audio, video, imovie, video-editing

I have recorded video and audio with two completely independent devices. Now I want to join those two together in iMovie and export the resulting video.

I have perfectly synced up the two, and when I play the video within iMovie, everything is perfect. However, after the export, in the resulting file the video is lagging ever so slightly. From what I see there is no shift happening as the video progresses. It's just the same constant lag.

Now I could of course try to make it slightly out of sync in iMovie and hope that the resulting video is in sync. But I don't want to hack this. I have tried various export settings, with the same result. I am also aware of [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383208/audio-out-of-sync-after-exporting-from-imovie), however my audio track is at 48 KHz already, so that should be fine.

The only editing I did in iMovie was syncing audio and video, and cutting off some parts in the beginning and end.

**EDIT**

The `MediaInfo` output for the orignal video file. Please note: While there is an audio track, the audio recording was actually muted, I am not using it:

```
General
Complete name                            : <redacted>.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42 (isom/mp42)
File size                                : 209 MiB
Duration                                 : 9 min 11 s
Overall bit rate                         : 3 173 kb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2022-04-05 17:14:56
Tagged date                              : UTC 2022-04-05 17:14:56

Video
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L5
Format settings                          : CABAC / 11 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 11 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 9 min 11 s
Bit rate                                 : 3 044 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.132
Stream size                              : 200 MiB (96%)
Title                                    : H.264/AVC video
Encoded date                             : UTC 2022-04-05 17:14:56
Tagged date                              : UTC 2022-04-05 17:14:56
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 9 min 11 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 126 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel layout                           : C
Sampling rate                            : 32.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 31.250 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 8.30 MiB (4%)
Title                                    : AAC audio
Encoded date                             : UTC 2022-04-05 17:14:56
Tagged date                              : UTC 2022-04-05 17:14:56
```

This is the `MediaInfo` for the original audio file. It was recorded with Presonus Studio One, so I could export the audio in a different format if necessary:

```
General
Complete name                            : <redacted>.mp3
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 19.2 MiB
Duration                                 : 8 min 23 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 320 kb/s
Performer                                : <redacted>
Recorded date                            : 2022
Writing library                          : LAME3.100
BPM                                      : 130

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Format settings                          : Joint stereo
Duration                                 : 8 min 23 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 320 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 41.667 FPS (1152 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 19.2 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : LAME3.100
Encoding settings                        : -m j -V 4 -q 2 -lowpass 20.5
```

Finally, this is the `MediaInfo` output for resulting video file when I choose Quality `Best (ProRes)`, but it's the same with all settings:

```
General
Complete name                            : <redacted>.mov
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : QuickTime
Codec ID                                 : qt   0000.00 (qt  )
File size                                : 1.95 GiB
Duration                                 : 4 min 25 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 63.1 Mb/s
Movie name                               : <redacted>
Movie_More                               : <redacted>
Description                              : <redacted>
Encoded date                             : UTC 2022-04-06 19:07:08
Tagged date                              : UTC 2022-04-06 19:07:39
Writing library                          : Apple QuickTime
Cover                                    : Yes
Keyword                                  : iMovie
com.apple.quicktime.keywords             : iMovie
com.apple.quicktime.title                : <redacted>

Video
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : ProRes
Format version                           : Version 0
Format profile                           : 422
Codec ID                                 : apcn
Duration                                 : 4 min 25 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 60.8 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 2.640
Stream size                              : 1.88 GiB (96%)
Title                                    : Core Media Video
Writing library                          : Apple
Encoded date                             : UTC 2022-04-06 19:07:08
Tagged date                              : UTC 2022-04-06 19:07:39
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : PCM
Format settings                          : Little / Signed
Codec ID                                 : lpcm
Duration                                 : 4 min 25 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 2 304 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth                                : 24 bits
Stream size                              : 73.0 MiB (4%)
Title                                    : Core Media Audio
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2022-04-06 19:07:08
Tagged date                              : UTC 2022-04-06 19:07:39

Other
ID                                       : 3
Type                                     : Time code
Format                                   : QuickTime TC
Duration                                 : 4 min 25 s
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Time code of first frame                 : 00:00:00:00
Time code of last frame                  : 00:04:25:18
Time code, striped                       : Yes
Title                                    : Core Media Time Code
Encoded date                             : UTC 2022-04-06 19:07:08
Tagged date                              : UTC 2022-04-06 19:07:39
```

I am on Monterey 12.3.1, iMovie 10.3.1, and I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports) with an 2,3 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7.

Comment: In what format is the resultant output file? Also, what Mac model, macOS and iMovie versions, please!

Comment: I have just added all that to my question.